# Multiple curves using ZedGraph

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I have a strange thing happening while using [ZedGraph](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx).

I am using the same item to add multiple curves. Like:

```
ZedGraph LineItem curve_3;
curve_3 = pane.AddCurve("", xx_1, yy, xxyy);
```

I call the above lines multiple times to add multiple points. But when I remove the curve, only the last added curve gets removed and left all stays on the pane.

```
this.zedGraph_RenderedTrack.GraphPane.CurveList.Remove(curve_3);
```

I am not finding a way that will clear all the curves added. Is there a to do it?

My actual requirement is that I have to add the different lines dynamically on the pane, but I don't need to display the label information and all of them should be plotted by a single click and removed by a single click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are holding only the last curve in this code:

```
ZedGraph LineItem curve_3;
curve_3 = pane.AddCurve("", xx_1, yy, xxyy);
```

Use collection like List<LineItem> to remember all the curves.

```
List<LineItem>.foreach(r => this.zedGraph_RenderedTrack.GraphPane.CurveList.Remove(r);
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all curves from your graph pane, simply use the `CurveList.Clear()` method:

```
this.zedGraph_RenderedTrack.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
```

Comment: actually i dont want to remove all but only few which i have added through curve_3. left all the data i want to keep and thus we cant use the CurveList.Clear();

Comment: In that case, the approach that JesseJames proposes should be the way to go: collect your added curves in a separate list and then loop through the list and remove all items from the `GraphPane.CurveList`.